# Why are my add methods for arraylists conflicting, how can I edit my custom add method

Tags: java

I've figured out why my arraylist was always returning a size of 0 but I can't fix the problem. I have a custom model with an "addHuman(Human h) method that is intended to add to an array. Only problem is that it doesn't. Now, if I were to use the regular method, say model.add(index, object o) it would actually work and increment the size of my arraylist but doesn't display on my jtable. My question is how can I make this work for my custom addHuman method? Any help much appreciated!

and the following is the main class that uses that method. When I click on the button to addIndividual, it's supposed to add the human to my HumanListModel:

```
addIndividual.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{

    Human temp;

    try {

        temp = new Human();         
        modelx.addHuman(indexPoint, temp); 
///the addHuman method does display on jtable but doesn't increment arraylist, meaning that the size is always 0 which creates many problems/////

                   //modelx.add(indexPoint, temp); does indeed increment the arraysize but then it doesn't display the values on the jtable////

        indexPoint++;



        System.out.println(modelx.size());  
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
    newbiex.revalidate(); ////is the jtable////
                }
    });
```

here is my custom HumanListModel:

```
public class HumanListModel extends DefaultListModel implements TableModel
{

    private ArrayList<Human> data;

    public HumanListModel()
    {
        super();
        data = new ArrayList<Human>();
    }

public void addHuman(int k, Human h)
{
    data.add(k, h);
    fireIntervalAdded(this, data.size(), data.size());

}

    public Human getHuman(int o)
    {
        return data.get(o);
    }

    public void removeHuman(Human h)
    {
        data.remove(h);
    }

    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        // the number of columns you want to display
        return 1;
    }

    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
    {
        return (row < data.size()) ? data.get(row) : null;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col)
    {
        return "Human";

    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int col)
    {
        return Human.class;
    }

    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return false;
}

public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
    }


public void setValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fire model changes when you change the data underlying the

```
public void addHuman(Human h)
{
   data.add(h); 
    fireIntervalAdded(this, data.size(), data.size());
}
```

Similar methods with similar events need calling whenever you change the underlying data to tell the List that it has to update the screen image.

For example, `removeHuman()` will need a similar call. Consult the javadoc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html for the methods that do that. (In this example, `fireIntervalRemoved()` and the event will need to contain the index of the row removed.)

You are going to also need a `getElementAt()` method that returns the data element for that row. In your case, return the `Human` at that row but it will need a `toString()` method. Alternately, you could format a string from the `Human` 
and return it.

*Note* - A previous version of this answer was based on my confusion, thinking this was a TableModel and not a ListModel. It's been fixed.

Comment: where do I add that? And how can I make my addHuman method work? :(

Comment: And addTableModelListener() and removeTableModelListener() shouldn't be overridden with empty methods

Comment: I'm not sure what to put in those methods yet, I haven't gotten there yet :/

Comment: Use the versions of those listener related methods in the parent classes. You can just take yours out.

Comment: Hey Lee, I add that line however it tells me to create the variable model, but my Humanlistmodel was created in my main class. Whaat variable do I actually put there???

Comment: @Iron Sorry. Fixed that. I copied the line from the online javadocs for `DefaultTableModel` and left that in.

Comment: Quick question: I edited my addHuman method to include the index I want to add the object, the reason I do that is to increment the index each time I add one. let me know if that is ok. I removed the model from the code but it's still giving me the error indication thereat :/

Comment: It depends on what you did with that index. If you added an index parameter to the method, that will work. If you are keeping a variable with the size of the list, that's redundant because you can always use `data.size()` to find that.

Comment: It says that the method is undefined for HumanListModel which has been a great source of pain in having used a listmodel lol, also, for the ValueAt method i def have a toString method defind in my Human class, one of the few things I've done right with this project, ihaven't yet defined all the methods but i'm working my up the difficulty level

Comment: Edited answer to make it based on a ListModel instead of a TableModel. Try the new version. You do have a JList, right? I just noticed it says `implements TableModel`. Don't mix tables and lists.

Comment: Actually yes I do have a jtabel created in the main class. My jtable is added to a scrollpane. So I added that line and no more error :) but my list size doesn't seem to wanna go above zero. I edited my code so you can see how I attempted to fix it. I need to have the indexPoint variable to increment the array to avoid returning size 0 each time. Your code is working though so thank you very much!

Comment: If you have a JTable, you would be better off using DefaultTableModel and those methods I had before. You can find them in the history on this answer, if you want to do it.